# React Native - Horizontal scroll with columns

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-flatlist

I'm trying to implement the following [view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJMfv.jpg) where each column is limited to 4 rows of song details in a horizontal FlatList. I have managed to create each row with song details + purchase button in a [single component](http://blob:https://imgur.com/559107e5-1840-4d0e-84b2-5860017f5d69).

However, I'm struggling to limit each column to just 4 row of results.  I'm currently rendering each component with a map function:

```
renderBestOfTheWeek = (items) => {
  return (
    <View>
      {items.map((item, index) => <SongItemHorizontalScroll item={item} key={index} />)}
    </View>
  )
}

render() {
  return (
    <FlatList
      data={this.state.bestOfTheWeek}
      horizontal={true}
      renderItem={this.renderBestOfTheWeek}
    />
  )
}
```

`SongItemHorizontalScroll` component:

```
   <View style={containerStyle}>
      <Image
        source={{ uri: thumbnail_image }}
        style={albumImageStyle}
      />
      <View style={songDetailButtonContainer}>
        <View style={songInfoStyle}>
          <Text
            style={{ fontSize: 12, lineHeight: 14, width: 160 }}
            numberOfLines={1}>
            {title}
          </Text>
          <Text
            style={{ color: '#666', fontSize: 12, lineHeight: 14, width: 160 }} numberOfLines={1}
          >{artist} - {album}</Text>
        </View>
        <Button onPress={() => Linking.openURL(url)} price={price} />
      </View>
    </View>
```

My data have been structured as such and is currently stored in state.

```
0: (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
1: (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
2: (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
3: (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
```

However I'm receiving the following error message (**TypeError: items.map is not a function**).

Where did I go wrong and what would be the proper method of achieving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @Foyarash suggestion and help, here's the solution:

```
renderBestOfTheWeek = ({ item }) => {
    return (
        <View>
            {item.map((songs, index) => <SongItemHorizontalScroll item={songs} key={index} />)}
        </View>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like somewhere `items` became an Object instead of an Array like it was meant to be. Try making it an Array again.

```
renderBestOfTheWeek = (items) => {
  return (
    <View>
      {Array.from(items).map((item, index) => <SongItemHorizontalScroll item={item} key={index} />)}
    </View>
  )
}
```

Comment: That seems to do away with the error message. However, I'm now passing an array of 4 objects into each SongItemHorizontalScroll component rather than each object.

Answer (score 0):

The renderItem function receives an object containing the keys item and index.

Thus, you should have

```
renderBestOfTheWeek = ({ item }) => {
```